# How to add value to previous row if condition is met

Tags: r, if-statement, row

What I am trying to do is if a row in column b is equal to 2 then I want to add 3 to the value of the previous row in column a. And if the condition is not met, then I don't want the previous row value to change. When I try this code however R is adding to the subsequent row. And it doesn't matter what I replace the -1 row reference with it always adds to the subsequent row.

```
df$a[-1] <- ifelse(df$b == 2, df$a[-1] + 3, df$a[-1])

Have                               Want
a b                                a b
0 1                                0 1
1 3                                4 3
2 2                                2 2
2 4                                2 4
4 5                                4 5
```

Comment: Also, you don't pay extra for code whitespace on SO, it's included in the membership plan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(0, 1, 2, 2, 3),
             b=c(1, 3, 2, 4, 4))

df$a[c(df$b[-1], 0) == 2] <- df$a[c(df$b[-1], 0) == 2] + 3
```

Comment: You might want to factor the common condition into a separate line.

Answer (score 3):

**One solution:**

I'd find it easiest just to work with the vectors directly, like so:

```
df$a <- df$a + c((df$b[-1] == 2) * 3, 0)
```

**The issue with your code:**

You're getting the subsequent row in your statement because each element of the first argument, `df$b==2` matches to the next row of `df$a`. Let's look at the example in your question to illustrate:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(0,1,2,2,4), b=c(1,3,2,4,5))  # As in your question
```

Here, `df$b==2` is equivalent to `c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)`.

`df$a[-1]` is all the elements of `df$a`, except the first i.e. equivalent to `c(1,2,2,4)`. Because the argument lengths differ, the first element of `df$a[-1]` is repeated / looped, like `c(1,2,2,4,1)`.

Therefore, in your statement, the first element of `df$b==2` is matched to the first element of `df$a[-1]`, or the second element of `df$a` (i.e. the subsequent row), and the second element of `df$b==2` is matched to the third element of `df$a` etc.

In this example, your code would give the following output:

```
ifelse(df$b==2, df$a[-1]+3, df$a[-1])
# Output: 1 2 5 4 1
```

**A way to adjust your code:**

Because you want to compare the second element of `df$b` to the first of `df$a` and so on, you could adjust your code as follows:

```
df$a[-nrow(df)] <- ifelse(df$b[-1]==2, df$a+3, df$a)
```

If any of my explanations are unclear, feel free to comment and I'll try to help!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. It helped me to understand the logic better on my initial attempt, and why that failed.